# How to show product details in popup when click link in custom grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to show admin product grid in a popup window when we click link products in the custom admin grid in Magento 2. Please refer the attached screenshots. Please help us with some solution. [image]

Comment: You use UI component?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh How to make a Ui component for -  If we want to show all details of a row in Popup in admin grid ?